# Unable to Import module to EFS for Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am using AWS Lambda python3.8 runtime, and for the filesystem, I am using EFS.

On Lambda I am using openCV, which is returning such kind of error upon Lambda function invoke:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libpng16.so.16: cannot 
    open shared object file: No such file or directory"
}
```

I guess libpng16 dependencies were needed in order to make it work, but couldn't find exact steps where to put this lib on the mounted directory of EFS?

Comment: How did you package your OpenCV dependency? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You would normally include an _operating-system-appropriate_ build of any shared libraries in your uploaded ZIP file. If you want to store them on a separately-mounted EFS instance, you'll need to update `sys.path`. However, you need a good understanding of the import system to do this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: @sakthisrinivas I have packaged OpenCV dependency with [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency) guide (except zipping section), which gave me three directories *cv2*, *opencv_python.libs* and *opencv_python-4.5.4.58.dist-info*. After that i placed them in the local mount path of EFS.